# Apache Camel - Context getting closed before job ends

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am creating a basic route to copy files from one folder to another.

My ultimate goal, if to have a multiple routes in my application, and every route will be invoked as a step in batch process, one after the other. So I will have to start and stop camel context for each route.

I have written following code.

But camel context end's before completing the job.

I can't put thread sleep, as I am not sure how much time job will take.

Any help in this regard will be great help.

```
public class FileTransporter {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    HdfsRouteBuilder1 anotherRouteBuilder =new HdfsRouteBuilder1();

    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

    try{
        ctx.addRoutes(anotherRouteBuilder);

        ctx.start();

        ctx.stop();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end of main method
}

public class HdfsRouteBuilder1 extends RouteBuilder{

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("file://E:/test/?noop=true")
    .threads(1)
    .to("file://E:/test1/");
}
}
```

I also tried using oncompletion() option, in route, but that also doesn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ about running Camel standalone: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html and in particular this link: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply. This solves 50% of problem. Issue I am facing over here is, how to stop the context manually when all the processing is finished. As after i execute 'main.run()' control doesn't come back to main class again.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html. And you can use the `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true` on the file endpoint to known when its empty and then stop the route or camel itself, for latter see http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

Comment: Also this has been asked before on SO how to stop Camel when there is no more files/messages. So search here or google a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Camel's MainSupport classes may be what you want.

If you only expect to copy one file, then the following will also work:

Pass a CountDownLatch to the constructor of your HdfsRouteBuilder1.  Then call await on the CountDownLatch after your call to ctx.start.

Inside your HdfsRouteBuilder1, count down the latch after it's done.

If you expect there to be more than one file, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly closing the context just after starting it. This doesn't allow it enough time to receive and process events. The `start` method doesn't block (at least in camel 2).

You need to block after Camel start. For that you have some options:

- Block using `Thread.currentThread().join();` just after `ctx.start();`
- Block using the camel utility class, See [thiese javadocs](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/main/MainSupport.html)

Comment: Thread.currentThread().join() will cause the program to never halt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.sleep(Time_in_millisecond) after starting camel context.
Or else you can use camel main instead of DefaultCamelContext.

```
Main main = new Main();
main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(anotherRouteBuilder);
main.run();
```